# Cannot load script in ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I created a `ViewComponent` which display a `Table` that require some plugin for enable specific functionalities. Inside the `ViewComponent` I tried to create a specific section:

```
@section DataTableScripts{
   <script src="~/js/JQuery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
}
```

unfortunately I discovered that a `ViewComponent` cannot load a `@section`.

So I tried to include the script directly in the `ViewComponent`, but the problem is that the scripts are loaded before of `JQuery` which is loaded inside the `_Layout`, specifically:

*ViewComponent*

```
<script src="~/js/JQuery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/JQuery/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/JQuery/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/JQuery/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/JQuery/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/JQuery/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/JQuery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

*Layout*

```
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so in this case I'll get:

> jQuery is not defined

How can I manage this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the `Layout` for your ViewComponent .

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@section DataTableScripts{
    <div>It works </div>
    <script src="~/js/JQuery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
}
```

Here's the screenshot that works :

[image]

**[Edit]**

This approach does not seems a good way to do that . As [@Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin) says , this will make the `Layout` render twice . Another patch is to write a new `RefinedLayout.cshtml` and set the `Layout` of `ViewComponent` as the `RefinedLayout` :

```
@{
    Layout = "_RefinedLayout.cshtml";
}

@section DataTableScripts{
    <div>It works </div>
    <script src="~/js/JQuery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
}
```

For more information , refer [workaround by MortenMeisler](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2910#issuecomment-356276338)

Comment: But now you have a `Layout` that's double-nested and rendered *twice*.

Comment: @KirkLarkin You're right .  I just found [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2910) .  It seems that someone has found this problem before . I have to say it's not a good idea and the workaround is rather ugly . Thank you very much .

Comment: @Charanoglu I'm so sorry about that  . I've just tested with a new `RefinedLayout.cshtml` (thanks to the workaround by MortenMeisler ) . It will work .

Comment: @itminus only a thing: should I duplicate the scripts already defined inside the `ViewComponent`? Honestly I don't understand at all the workaround

Comment: @Charanoglu Just duplicate the dependencies only .  If I understand correctly , your `DataTableScripts` has only a depenency on the `jQuery` lib , so just duplicate the `jquery.min.js` . Note the viewfile that renders ViewModel should not render the section of ` jquery.min.js` again .

Comment: @itminus but this "solution" have no sense, at this point is better add the `jquery.min.js` in each section instead of make the code more intricated, it's a shame that Microsoft didn't provided a solution for this

Comment: @Charanoglu When I realized that I made a mistake , I google it and found that  a lot of developers had  encoutered  this issue before .  Ok , I have to admit that the default behavior of `ViewComponent.Layout`  does make sense . However , I cannot figure a better way to do that . Maybe Microsoft will provide us a nicer way in future .

Answer (score 0):

You are using`<script src="~/js/JQuery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>` twice. Just keep it once.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying another layout for viewcomponents with scripts will duplicate scripts. And @section is just ignored during rendering.
So I replaced jquery document ready with plain javascript domcontentloaded and any jquery can be written inside domcontentloaded. Not a permanent good approach but works for me.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    console.log($ === jQuery)
});
</script>
```