# Cannot load jquery before other script

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I need to load `JQuery` before anything else, so I created this code inside `_Layout`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body class="sidebar-enable" data-keep-enlarged="true">
    <div class="wrapper">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("DataTableScript", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I have a `ViewComponent` called `ProductsViewComponent`, I load it inside a `View` called `Home` in this way:

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("Products", new { date = "2018-09-05" })
```

Inside the `ViewComponent` I need to load the `DataTableScript` (which requires JQuery for works properly), so I created this logic inside the `Default.cshtml` (which is the html of `ProductsViewComponent`):

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_LayoutViewComponent.cshtml";
}

@section DataTableScript{
    <script src="~/js/vendor/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/vendor/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/vendor/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/vendor/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/vendor/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/dataTable.js"></script>
}
```

I have specified another `Layout` because the `ViewComponent` is not able to render a section (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199481/cannot-load-script-in-viewcomponent) question for further information)

inside the `_LayoutViewComponent` I placed this code:

```
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("DataTableScript")
```

Essentially `RenderBody` calls `_Layout` and then the `DataTableScript` are loaded. But when I start the application I get the `DataTableScript` loaded before of `JQuery` and this is really weird because in the `_Layout` I specified to load the `DataTableScript` after `JQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a partial to render your script tags.

**Views/Shared/_DataTableScriptsPartial.cshtml**

```
<script src="~/js/vendor/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/vendor/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/vendor/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/vendor/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/vendor/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/vendor/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/dataTable.js"></script>
```

In your `_Layout.cshtml` declare a `scripts` section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @RenderSection("head", required: false)
</head>
<body class="sidebar-enable" data-keep-enlarged="true">
    <div class="wrapper">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

In the page that uses your ViewComponent render the partial in the scripts section.

**Products.cshtml**

```
@{ 
    Layout = "_Layout"; 
}

@await Component.InvokeAsync("Products", new { date = "2018-09-05" })

@section scripts {
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_DataTableScriptsPartial")
}
```

Comment: Amazing Brad! This is the solution that I'm looking for! Seems works really good, it this a good practice too? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a layout for a view component view. It's essentially a partial view. By the time the view component is processed the main layout is already set in stone. You should use a script loading library to conditionally include your additional scripts, and then externalize the JavaScript that serves your view component and have it run after the associated scripts are finished loading.

There's various different libraries/techniques you can use for this: CommonJS, AMD, RequireJS, etc. You'll need to do some research and figure out which is the best fit for you. However, this is a transformative thing. It will change the entire way you handle scripts with your application and might require some major restructuring of anything existing, as a result.

The easier approach is to simply just include the script in your main layout. If your layout includes this view component, then it's always going to need the scripts anyways, so just go ahead make it static. It doesn't have a the warm fuzzies of a completely self-contained unit of functionality that you're wanting your view component to be, but to get there is going to likely require far more effort that is warranted or reasonable for this one particular scenario.

For what it's worth, you can optimize things a bit by front-loading the scripts using the `<link rel="preload" href="..." as="script" />` tag. This would go in your head, and prompt supporting browsers to go ahead and load in the script, without actually running it (which is the part that blocks rendering). Then, by the time you actually include the script before the closing body tag, it's likely already good to go, and the script tag will simply prompt the browser to run it.

**UPDATE**

One further options is to use a client-side library that supports "components". This would be a replacement for your view component, not something you'd add in addition to. However, the benefit of a client-side component is that you *can* contain all the JavaScript functionality in that and then the library simply runs over your document at the end and wires everything up. I personally like Vue, but there's other choices like React, Ember, Angular, etc. Consult with the documentation for each to evaluate if you might prefer this approach instead and which particular library you prefer. They all essentially do the same thing, but they each have their own unique ways of getting there.

I like Vue personally because it's light-weight and largely unobtrusive. It doesn't necessarily force you to do things in a certain way, so you can have a bit more freedom in that respect. Libraries like React and Angular tend to be more opinionated, and since they're geared more towards creating single page applications, can sometimes make it difficult to split responsibilities with server-side rendering such as Razor views. Just my opinion though.

Comment: Mmm you guess the best option is using `preload` instead of install other third party libs?

Comment: Preload is just an optimization hint. It's not a replacement for anything per se. My only point there was that if your concern with including them in the layout was page weight/render time, there's ways to mitigate that somewhat.

Comment: I have 15 scripts or something, I'll try with the preload

Comment: That's quite a lot of scripts. Modern browsers are better about loading resources, but you can still run into simultaneous connection limits. You should really use something like Gulp, Webpack, etc. to concat and minify those.

Comment: Are you able to give me an example with one of those libraries? I don't know nothing of them, thanks

Comment: Here's a simple Todo app written with Vue components. https://codesandbox.io/s/o29j95wx9 The docs of each library are your best friend here, though.